# How do I check when CenteredNorm was included in Matplotlib? And hence if it is available in Matplotlib 3.3.2

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, colormap

I am trying to use [CenteredNorm](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html#centered) but despite my matplotlib version being quite recent, it appears to not be available. Any clue of what can be the problem?

How can I check if my Matplotlib version is recent enough to include CenteredNorm? I.e. How do I check in which Matplotlib version CenteredNorm was included?

[image]

**EDIT**: Keeping this question up just for others who are like I was, i.e. don't know how to check for when (in which version) a function was included in Matplotlib repository, or any other repo.

**ANSWER IS** AS @DeepSpace commented:
"Sometimes it will say it right in the docs. In this case it did not, so I used "git blame" in the GitHub repo and saw that the commit that added it is tagged with 3.4.0: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/4b2f1052252d103b7abb68cf536a18d1b14b1077
Me: "I don't know how to do git blame on a repo that is not sitting on my machine."
@DeepSpace: "There is a "blame" button when viewing a file in GitHub UI"

Comment: Having a "quite recent" version is not the same as "the latest" version. `CenteredNorm` appears to have been added in `3.4`, so having `3.3.2` (as recent as it may be) is a problem

Comment: You can read different versions of the docs: https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html#centered  As you can see `CenteredNorm` does not appear.    BTW, you really don't need `CenteredNorm` - just use the regular norm and center `vmin` and `vmax` on whatever you want the center to be.

Comment: Thanks, @JodyKlymak. I wanted to set vcenter, without needing to have symmetric vmin and vmax. I can't do that with Normalize, can I?

Comment: Converting from vmin = vcenter-dv, vmax=vcenter+dv is pretty trivial.

Comment: @DeepSpace, thank you I tried to check when it was added but did not know how. How did you find that it was added in 3.3.2?

Comment: @JodyKlymak, I just said that It is not symmetric. That would not work for my case. I want zero to be gray in a `coolwarm` colormap. With, for example, the range going from -0.5 to 1.5.

Comment: Then you want TwoSlopeNorm.

Comment: I wanted to keep the same slope, hence the `CenteredNorm`

Comment: If you have a colormap that goes from 0 to 255, and you want 0 to map to 128, -0.5 to map to 0, and 1.5 to map to 255, then you need two slopes.

Comment: I do not want -0.5 to map to zero. I want to keep the same slope.

Comment: @HomeroEsmeraldo Sometimes it will say it right in the docs. In this case it did not, so I used "git blame" in the GitHub repo and saw that the commit that added it is tagged with `3.4.0`: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/4b2f1052252d103b7abb68cf536a18d1b14b1077

Comment: @DeepSpace you need to have the repo downloaded to do that? Or is there a way to do that without having cloned the repo to ones computer?

Comment: @HomeroEsmeraldo Click on the link in my comment. It does not download anything.

Comment: Yes, I already clicked. I was just wondering how you found it. I do `git blame` on local repositories, but I don't know how I could have done it on matplotlib, since I don't know how to do `git blame` on a repo that is not sitting on my machine.

Comment: @HomeroEsmeraldo There is a "blame" button when viewing a file in GitHub UI

Comment: Found it. Thank you very much for your time and useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest stable release is 3.4.2. A simple update will do it

Comment: Thanks, I found that by using the "blame" button after finding where CenteredNorm is defined in the github repo (when viewing a file in GitHub UI as suggested by @DeepSpace)